# Is there a difference in the definition of the pth percentile in Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

The pth percentile of a set of n data can be calculated by the following steps:

Step 1: arrange the original data in ascending order.

Step 2: calculate i=n*p%.

Step 3: if i is not an integer and the next integer greater than i is j, the pth percentile is the jth data;

if i is an integer, the pth percentile is the average of the i-th and (i+1)-th data.

Using the above method, the 75th percentile of the data set {1, 1, 7, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7} is 6.5.

Why does the result obtained using code give 6? Is the definition different in Mathematica?

```
Quantile[{1, 1, 7, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7}, 3/4]
```

Comment: As stated in the documentation, for a vector `Quantile[data, p]` is calculated by `Sort[data][[Max[Ceiling[p*n], 1]]]` If you want a different definition, `Quantile[data,p,{{a,b},{c,d}}] uses the quantile definition specified by parameters a, b, c, d.`

Comment: @BobHanlon The second part of the comment is not appropriate. No choice of parameters `a, b, c, d` can produce the same result as requested by OP.

Comment: @azerbajdzan - Notwithstanding the formulas shown in the documentation, `Quantile[data, 3/4, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}]` evaluates to `13/2`, i.e., `6.5`

Comment: @BobHanlon This is just a coincidence. The method described by OP is not equivalent with any choice of parameters in `Quantile`, neither with `{{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}`. Try instead of `3/4`, say, `3/5` and you get different results for your code and for OP's method.